# Cannot Add WCF Refercence with Basic Authentication HTTPS

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, https

I made a WCF Service: HelloWorldService follow tips in [Implement HelloWorld Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97204/Implementing-a-Basic-Hello-World-WCF-Service) then hosted in IIS 8.5 (Windows 8.1) with Basic Authentication[image]

and my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment >
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
        relativeAddress="./HelloWorldService.svc"
        service="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="MyWCFServices.IHelloWorldService"
        bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name ="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I publish successful in try in Browser and Login with my username and password. It worked
[image]

But Error when I add service refercence, I cann't this with same my username and password on VS2013.
[image]
I try many times with username and password but I return dialog again
[image]
and I must click No.

This is Details:

> There was an error downloading 
>   https://localho.st/HelloWorldSecure/HelloWorldService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
>   https://localho.st/HelloWorldSecure/HelloWorldService.svc The
>   HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Basic realm=mylocalhost'. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized. If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Somebody help me make it correctly. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the authentication to Anonymous or Windows before trying to add the reference? Once you got the reference, you can change the authentication back to basic.

Comment: Oh thanks, I try Athentication is Windows, it work correctly, but I changed back to Basic and run service, it return an exception

Comment: You need to set the credentials in the client before you make the call.  Can you post the code you're using to connect to the service?

Comment: @Tim I cann't add service reference, not forget set the credentials